# Is there a way to check that class or object has a mixin in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, mixins

There is an example on Groovy's User Guide:

```
@Category(Vehicle) class FlyingAbility {
    def fly() { "I'm the ${name} and I fly!" }
}

@Category(Vehicle) class DivingAbility {
    def dive() { "I'm the ${name} and I dive!" }
}

interface Vehicle {
    String getName()
}

@Mixin(DivingAbility)
class Submarine implements Vehicle {
    String getName() { "Yellow Submarine" }
}

@Mixin(FlyingAbility)
class Plane implements Vehicle {
    String getName() { "Concorde" }
}

@Mixin([DivingAbility, FlyingAbility])
class JamesBondVehicle implements Vehicle {
    String getName() { "James Bond's vehicle" }
}
```

If I have an instance of `JamesBondVehicle`:

```
def vehicle = new JamesBondVechile()
```

How do I check that `vehicle` have a flying ability? Especially in case I don't know how the vehicle was created.

The following does not work:

```
assert vehicle instanceof FlyingAbility
```

The following works:

```
assert vehicle.respondsTo('fly')
```

But it's not a generic way to check the mixin presense e.g. what if I have 2 mixins that look exactly the same, but just implement stuff differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. I'm not an expert on Groovy, but I did a little digging and found this function in the codebase: [MixinInMetaClass.mixinClassesToMetaClass](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.1.4/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/MixinInMetaClass.java#MixinInMetaClass.mixinClassesToMetaClass%28groovy.lang.MetaClass,java.util.List%29)

If you look through the code there, it doesn't seem to do anything to actually preserve the names of the classes bing mixed in. Instead, it just loops through all their properties and merges them into the target class if there isn't a conflict.

Based of that, it sounds like `vehicle.respondsTo('fly')` is as close as you're going to get.